# how would I do some calculations with only bull candles over a given range?

Tags: pine-script

Hi I am looking to try and do some calculations with only bull candles over the last 50 candles for example. What would be the approach / logic for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hello Blake my friend,

Our best bet here is a for loop. We want to run an iteration that gains in an increment of one bar until the specified number is reached. For each iteration we need to perform an action, which we will specify under the loop length. Ill use an example where we add up all candles that were bullish over the last 50 bars.

```
//@version=4
study("My Script")

counter = 0.0

for i = 1 to 50 
    if close[i] > open[i] 
        counter += 1 
        
plot(counter)
```

Here we specify what "i" will be for each iteration, in this case we would like it to run starting one bar ago to the 50 bars prior to that one.

Then we make a statement to run a condition under. If our close is greater than we opened, we add one to the counter. This check will be performed each bar, so each time we start from counter = 0, and run it back adding 1 for all that were bullish.

Please note that if a person wanted this check to start on the current bar, and still have 50 bars in the check, then we would need to replace the length statement with a new starting point like this:

```
//@version=4
study("My Script")

counter = 0.0

for i = 0 to 49 
    if close[i] > open[i] 
        counter += 1 
        
plot(counter)
```

starting from 0 means we put 0 into the first [barsback] check of the historical operator, which will reference this bar.

Cheers and good luck with your trading and coding!

Comment: Thankyou Bjorgum, you have once again helped me out.  Its really appreciated. :)

Comment: Glad to help brother!